# Magento Double Products

Tags: magento

I'm having a magento installation with 2 websites and only one catalog. 
One website has 2 storeviews [ romanian and english ] as for the local visitors and for the rest of the world.

The thing is simple. When I add products, I add them only once [ as Default Value ] and from time to time I mass edit them, for the other storeviews, using the import/export function.

Now, I'm encountering some odd issue: some products that haven't been edited yet [ for the english version ], took different values from other products already translated and they repeat themselves.

I'll try to 'draw' somehow :

**Store view 1** [ same as Default Values ]      **Store view 2** [ english ]
Produs Lalala #1                   Product Lalala #1
Produs Lalala #2                   Product XYZ #1
Produs Lalala #3                   Product XYZ #1
Produs Lalala #4                   Product XYZ #1
Produs Lalala #5                   Product XYZ #1

I hope it's clear, cause I have difficulties describing this problem, in an easy-to-understand manner, even in my native language.

So, if any of you know had been through something similar or have an idea of why is this happening, i'd be glad to hear something from you.

Otherwise, what's the easiest method of listing the double product-names for a certain storeview?

All the best!

Comment: pls give a link to your website...

Answer (score 2):

If a product is visible at the frontend, that means it is created at the backend. So if you say that the product is visible multiple times that means the product is created with different values in the backend. It may be confusing because their names are same. Please check the products that are repeating with different values, you would definitely find the products created and they have those values,please also check the stores they are associated to, it will be easier to find as their names are same.